# Distances between joined points from angles

Tags: geometry

Let's say that we have a set of angles ($\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_n$). Every angle is described by three points in the 2D space. Assume that the points right next to each other are connected (something like a necklace - see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWZ8S.jpg)) and the distance between every immediate neighbors is constant (ie. $d_{ij} = x$ for $i = j-1$).

Is there a way to create a function that can calculate the distance between any pair of points based only on the angles? Is it possible to do it in 3D, where we would need an additional angle?

This function should be differentiable, meaning that for any $d_{ij}$ and $\alpha_k$ you can calculate $\frac{\partial d_{ij}}{\partial \alpha_k}$

Motivation: I am working on protein structure prediction, where in the first step I predict an inter-residue distance matrix. The structure of the protein backbone can be fully described by a set of dihedral angles. So, I would like to generate the structure (= set of dihedral angles), so that the induced distance matrix is as close as possible to the predicted distance matrix. The condition of differentiability is important because the plan is to solve the problem with either 1st or 2nd order optimization method.

Answer (score 2):

Your set of angles should be taken differently : you should use "signed" successive polar angles $\theta_k$ (a minus sign if one turns left, a plus sign if one turns right).

[image]

In this way the squared distance between endpoints is :

$$\underbrace{x^2 \left|\sum e^{i\theta_k}\right|^2}_{\text{complex version}}=x^2 \left[\left(\sum \cos \theta_k\right)^2+\left(\sum \sin \theta_k\right)^2 \right] \tag{1}$$

I prefer to manage squared distances, because it provides a smoother behavior.

Edit : in a 3D setting, the corresponding formula for the squared distances would use spherical coordinates

$$\begin{cases}x&=&r \sin \theta \cos \varphi\\
y&=&r \sin \theta \sin \varphi\\
x&=&r \cos \theta
\end{cases}$$

and the formula would be :

$$r^2 \left(\left(\sum(\sin \theta_k \cos \varphi_k)\right)^2+
\left(\sum(\sin \theta_k \sin \varphi_k)\right)^2+\left(\sum(\cos \theta_k)\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: Yes! That's beautiful! I did not think of it this way. Thank you very much @JeanMarie :)

Comment: I have been working on a modelization involving random broken lines like these ones a long time ago (random meaning here uniform distribution on angles in $(0,2\pi)$). There is a nice result saying that if the broken line has $n$ segments, then the mathematical expectation of the squares of the distances (shortest distance between endpoints) is $E(D^2)=n$  (a good diffusion model in $\approx \sqrt{n}$)

Comment: That's interesting. Is there any research paper/other resources related that I can read? I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: A good keyword for that is ["random walks'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).